# Is there a way to show caret in a disabled textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, caret

I want all the disabled textboxes in my application to have carets in them when they are focused. This would allow users to select and copy part of the text without using a mouse.

I'm ok with writing templates. I have tried IsReadOnly instead of IsEnabled but readonly doesn't show carets either. Carets only need to be shown when the user focuses on the textbox same as the default behavior of a non-readonly enabled textbox.

I'm not sure if this is even possible so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot set the focus on diabled controls nor can you copy the text. IsReadOnly would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so all I had to do was to set IsReadOnlyCaretVisible to true.

In order for it to affect all the textboxes in my application I've added fallowing code to my AppStyle.xml

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnlyCaretVisible" Value="True"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You can check the tick mark next to the Answer to accept and close your own answer.

Comment: Please check the tick mark next to the Answer to accept and close your own answer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I will but I need to wait two days before accepting my own answer apparently